# \includegraphics that works differently within and outside of figure environment

Tags: beamer, macros

I want to redefine `\includegraphics` so that while it works as usual within a `figure` environment, it is centered automatically outside of `figure` environments.

This is my try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\let\old@includegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{
    \ifx\@currenvir\@figureenvname
        \old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \else
        \begin{center}\old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}\end{center}
    \fi}
\newcommand*\@figureenvname{figure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This works as intended (first figure centered and second figure left aligned).

But once I use this command in `beamer`, it no longer works:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\let\old@includegraphics\includegraphics
\renewcommand\includegraphics[2][]{
    \ifx\@currenvir\@figureenvname
        \old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}
    \else
        \begin{center}\old@includegraphics[#1]{#2}\end{center}
    \fi}
\newcommand*\@figureenvname{figure}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Both figures are centered. What is the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: It is imho a quite bad idea to change \includegraphics like this.  Every code that assumes that you can insert a graphic in running text will fall over.

Comment: beside this: the figure environment in beamer is defined as a center environment.

Comment: @user182849 Why don't you just place the image in a `figure` environment?

Comment: If you really need a command that behaves like this, you should choose a different name for it instead of overwriting `\includegraphics`.

Comment: `\includegraphics` is an inline construct positioned just like a letter `X` so making it add `center` is really strange. the usual way to address this use case is to add `\centering` to the default layout of `figure`  which is directly supported by latex (just add it to the end of `\@floatboxreset`)